# Not able to feed full calendar with json events

Tags: php, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am trying the below code.. 
Integrating fullcalendar:-

```
<doctype! html>
    <html lang="urf-8">
    <head>
    <title>Full calendar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fullcalendar.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cal').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
            theme: true,
            header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
            editable: false,
            events: "json-events.php",
    })
    });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cal" ></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Json-events.php code:-

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    $query = "select * from calendar";

    $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $events = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $eventsArray['id'] =  $row['calendar_id'];
        $eventsArray['title'] = $row['subject'];
        $eventsArray['start'] = mktime($row['start_date_time']);
        $events[] = $eventsArray;
    }
    echo json_encode($events);
    ?>
```

For debugging when i access json-events.php i am getting the result, but no events are displaying in fullcalendar.

Please help me..

Comment: inspect the AJAX request in browser console to see if it is being made, also see if any errors thrown

Comment: also is date format proper for `mktime()`? ...seems unusual format to store date

Comment: @charlietfl do in need to check weather ajax calls are happening? if that is your 1st comment then i am using ajax in other examples which is working fine.. and even if i remove that mktime() events are not rendered

Comment: but have you checked the request. You can inspect it in a console and see the status, data returned etc? Is date in proper format for calendar also?

Comment: @charlietfl `[{"id":"1","title":"Ravi's birthday","start":"2012-11-22 00:00:00"},{"id":"2","title":"Rinkus Wedding","start":"2012-11-23 00:00:00"},{"id":"3","title":"Alokic Joining Date","start":"2012-11-05 00:00:00"},{"id":"4","title":"Consult Doctor","start":"2012-12-25 00:00:00"},{"id":"5","title":"Alokic Technologies 4th week","start":"2012-12-26 00:00:00"},{"id":"6","title":"Kasab Died","start":"2012-12-22 07:00:00"}]` this is how it is rendering

Comment: try converting to UNIX timestamp your date format isn't valid for Date object in javascript  Use [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: @charlietfl Yes your right .... now all my events are feeded..

Comment: @charlietfl Hey buddy please post your suggestion as answer to accept it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem lies in format of your date strings in JSON. Format is not compatible with date formats for plugin. If you convert to UNIX timestamps using `strtotime()` in php they will work.